# capistrano error when deploying with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

My `cap deploy:migrate` has suddenly stopped working, with an error:

```
*** [err :: 1.2.3.4:2222] bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file command finished in 559ms
failed: "/usr/local/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p0@gemset' -c 'cd /home/user/app/releases/20111122182205 && #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0xa6a0cc> RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate'" on 1.2.3.4:2222
```

Obviously the error has something to do with this not being a valid command ... `#<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0xa6a0cc>`

But I have no idea what changed recently that could cause it. Any ideas?

**update**

I know nothing of my code changed, but I may have fiddled with environments.  I'm wondering if it could be due to different gemsets and versions of capistrano.  It appears like different versions exist between with and without bundle exec calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and in my case it was related to a clash between a namespace and a variable. Basically, what happened was:

set :user, 'some user'

namespace :user do ; end

So whenever I was trying to reference the user variable I instead would be getting the namespace. I changed namespace :user to namespace :users and it's all good.

**final solution** *(edited by OP)*

This was nearly on the money.  The asset pipeline code included a call to `#{rake}` which conflicted with a recipe I had picked up for running code on the remote server, which had a `namespace :rake` line.  Changing my rake namespace fixed the problem.

Comment: +1. I had the same thing happen. I had a namespace in my deploy.rb called :rake, for executing rake tasks remotely. I changed it to :raketask

Comment: @EricGoldberg Exactly what happened to me. I like having a `rake` namespace aesthetically but I guess it'll have to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected end of file errors typically occur from not closing a block or operators like parentheses.  Or you may be missing the `do` in a namespace block.  You should double check your syntax for anything that may not have been closed properly.

If you don't spot the error after proofreading the configuration it will help if you can update the question with your deploy.rb configuration.

Comment: Interesting, but my source control shows nothing has changed since it last worked.

Answer (score -1):

Write `#{Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0xa6a0cc}`

Comment: no, that is being output because something with capistrano is calling to_s and outputting the object id instead of the correct command, but I don't know where or why.

Comment: If that, then without definition of `deploy:migrate` we will do nothing.

Comment: It is a baked-in task in capistrano